# What does this review comment mean?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I seem to have gotten a manual review ban:

> This tag wiki was plagiarized: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15068393 Please take a look at the suggested edit before approving.
>   Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

I probably did something wrong, but I cannot comprehend what this means. Something was plagiarized? Can anybody explain?

Comment: Do you not know what the word "plagiarized" means?

Comment: @CodyGray It's not the words I do not understand, but the meaning as a whole. It says "Please take a look at the suggested edit", but as far as I can see from the answers above it should read "Please check if the text was plagiarized before approving"

Comment: plagiarism is one of the things you should look out for in the suggested edit when you look at it. Spelling, grammar and readability are some of the others.

Comment: It should have said "Please look more carefully at the suggested edit before approving." Sloppy wording on the part of the moderator who typed it in, I suppose. It should go without saying that you need to check for plagiarism. This doesn't just apply to tag wiki edits, by the way—it applies to *all* content on the site. Plagiarism is usually very easy to spot. In this case, you could have simply rejected the tag wiki for not actually describing the usage of the tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray You will never find it is plagiarized by "carefully looking at the suggested edit" alone, right?

Comment: Um yeah, I can predict it with 99% accuracy just by looking at the edit. Using a search engine to confirm is generally advised. It takes about 5 seconds.

Comment: @CodyGray To be honest, even when knowing it I would not have seen it in the above case just by looking at the edit, seems like I'm less a genius than you. But I will refrain from reviewing tag-wikis in the future.

Comment: "In this case, you could have simply rejected the tag wiki for not actually describing the usage of the tag on Stack Overflow." What is being proposed here talks about what "you can use the QueryExpression class" to do. That is not a good tag wiki for Stack Overflow, since it doesn't *describe the purpose of the tag*. There is a rejection reason specifically for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that that tag wiki is copy-pasted from another site. Copy-pasting is epidemic in tag wikis.

We don't want copy-pasted content; at the very least, attribution should be provided. It's better to have content that is customized for the purpose of a tag wiki. A quick explanation of what it is, and then some more in-depth explanation and, if necessary, links to official sources for further reading.

When reviewing tag wikis, I find it best to use a search engine and see if the content is copy-pasted from somewhere.

Be especially aware if the suggested edit shows a highly professional writing style, or reads like promotion ("X is the fastest tool  to foo() your bar()"). Those are almost always copy-pasted from the official site for the product/service in question.

Comment: Ah, ok, so when reviewing tag-wikis we are supposed to actively google if it is plagiarized? Ok, thanks, this was new to me.

Comment: @Ctx It doesn't officially say that you have to Google. But unofficially the answer is "YES!"

Answer (score 5):

The text in the wiki is [taken verbatim from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328300.aspx) that's [plagiarism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plagiarism) (the copying of something without attribution) and is not allowed.

This is pretty common in tag wikis and you need to be prepared to check for it and reject the wiki edit.

If you find it too onerous to check for plagiarism, you need to stop reviewing tag wiki edits and learn to skip them instead.